# Lazy .NET. How to use it with list of objects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, lazy-loading

I have a webservice that implements a lazy handler that handles queries on db and fills list of structure. This is made to avoid to read from DB.
Basically I have:

```vb
Public Class Lazy_Handler
    Implements IDisposable
    
    Private lToRet As New List(Of External_Widget)        
    '[... other lists to be read from DB the first time]

    Private Shared ReadOnly lazy As Lazy(Of Lazy_Handler) = _
        New Lazy(Of Lazy_Handler)(Function() New Lazy_Handler())
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As Lazy_Handler
        Get
            Return lazy.Value
        End Get
    End Property
    
    Public Function list_of_external_widget() As List(Of External_Widget)
        Try
            If lToRet Is Nothing Then
                lToRet = New List(Of External_Widget)
            End If
    
            If lToRet.Count > 0 Then
                Return lToRet
            End If
            lToRet = New List(Of External_Widget)
    
            '... QUERY FROM DB HERE, DETAILS OMITTED
    
            Return lToRet
        Catch ex As Exception
            Purge("link_of_external_widget:" & ex.Message)
            Return New List(Of External_Widget)
        Finally
            DBOperazioni.CloseConn()
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

so from my website I call something like

```vb
Dim list_of_external_widget As List(Of Lazy_Handler.External_Widget) = _
    Lazy_Handler.Instance.list_of_external_widget()
```

I expect that the first time the lazy is created, then the query is executed. After that, no more lazy creations and no more queries on DB.
I'm right?

It works well, but sometimes (I don't know where) there something that becomes `Nothing` and I get error. What could it be?

Thank you

Comment: Are there any container-level initialization bits that you elided to minimize the example? As presented, there is basically no point to making the container `Lazy`, since all of the initialization happens when you call `list_of_external_widget` instead of when you create the container.  (This wouldn't make something become Nothing, it's just a broader observation on the design.)

Comment: I don't see anything that could produce `Nothing`.  As presented the function must always return a non-null list, and the instance operates through a .NET Lazy which I've never found any way to reset.

Comment: thanks @Craig for answering. there is a void function that I call to initialize the Lazy. after that the first time I call the function list_of_external_widget the query is executed then saved into the lToRet list. Starting from the second call, it should return lToRet list itself without performing any query. But, after a while (I think a day) something goes wrong and I can resume the website to proper behaviour by recycling the application on IIS.

Comment: Couple thoughts I've got.  Where exactly in the web app life cycle are you creating this, and where are you storing this list after creating it, are you sure that container isn't expiring as part of the std web app lifecycle?  Next, commonly when I implement lazy load patterns, I'll use a property rather than fields, then in the property Get, I can check the state of my value, then reload if required